# Where is this pointer freed in this simple ffmpeg example?

Tags: c, ffmpeg

I'm reading this simple ffmpeg decoding example: http://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/4.0/decode__video_8c_source.html. This part of the code called my attention:

```
while (data_size > 0) {
               ret = av_parser_parse2(parser, c, &pkt->data, &pkt->size,
                                      data, data_size, AV_NOPTS_VALUE, AV_NOPTS_VALUE, 0);
               if (ret < 0) {
                   fprintf(stderr, "Error while parsing\n");
                   exit(1);
               }
               data      += ret;
               data_size -= ret;
   
               if (pkt->size)
                   decode(c, frame, pkt, outfilename);
           }
```

As you can see, it passed `&pkt->data`, where `pkt->data` is already a pointer. So it passes a pointer to pointer. Therefore, it makes `pkt->data` point to a new allocated data on every call. Then, `pkt` is passed to decode: `decode(c, frame, pkt, outfilename);`. However, the data in `pkt->data` is never freed. I did not find any place where it is.

When the code finishes, it calls `av_packet_free(&pkt);`, but this would not be sufficient, because at every call to `av_parser_parse2`, `pkt->data` is pointed to a new pointer with new data. Where are all these new buffers being erased?

Answer (score 1):

FFMpeg uses reference counting to manage (some) packets. This document [AVPacket reference](https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/4.0/group__lavc__packet.html#ga1066464e7cdd1f215df6940db94e5d8e) mentions that av_free_packet() is only needed to explicitly delete the packet.

Look for `av_packet_unref` references in the code, this may explain the absence of `av_packet_free` call.